# How can I use solr in production, are there any critical problems?

Tags: html, encoding, solrnet

Is there any clean installation tutorial, must i use runsample.bat ?
Is there any problem reported  about encoding? Can i use for Non-English Languages?
I have a html column on my real database. Is there any issue to add it to Solr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any clean installation tutorial

For Solr, see the [SolrInstall wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall). For SolrNet, see [Mapping](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Mapping) and [Initialization](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Initialization) in the wiki. Also there are some tutorials around such as [this one](http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2010/01/full-text-search-using-solr-lucene-and.html).

> must i use runsample.bat

No, it's not *mandatory*. runsample.bat launches the sample web app, you can use it for guidance or as a starting point.

> Is there any problem reported about encoding?

If you use Tomcat, make sure to [configure it properly](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#URI_Charset_Config).

> Can i use for Non-English Languages?

Yes, you can. [SolrNet is tested against Unicode](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet.Tests/Integration.Sample/Tests.cs#L51).

> I have a html column on my real database. Is there any issue to add it to Solr?

No, there are no issues adding html content.